# Class template, custom container

Tags: c++, template, collections

So I wrote this `class template` for a custom container. Basically, it stores elements and their occurences. When an element is pushed into the container, if it already exists, all it does is increment its counter.

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <map>
#include <string>

//
// Template class for a tocc, or Thing Occurence Counter Container
//
template <class T>
class tocc
{
public:
    tocc();

    //
    // Increments the count of that item or creates a new pair if it doesn't exist
    //
    void push(const T& item)
    {
        // If no the item isn't found, create new pair with a count of 1
        if(_tocc.find(item) == _tocc.end())
            _tocc.insert(std::pair<T, long int>(item, 1));
        else
            _tocc.at(item)++;
    }

    //
    // Decrements the count of that item and erases it if the count reaches 0
    //
    void pop(const T& item)
    {
        // If the item is found
        if(_tocc.find(item) != _tocc.end())
            (_tocc.at(item) <= 1) ? _tocc.erase(item) : _tocc.at(item)--;

        // Do nothing if the item isn't found
    }

    //
    // Gets the count of a particular item
    // Returns the count if the item exists, 0 otherwise
    //
    long int getCount(const T& item)
    {
        if(_tocc.find(item) == _tocc.end())
            return 0;
        return _tocc.at(item);
    }

    //
    // Returns true if the item is present in the map, false otherwise
    //
    bool contains(const T& item)
    {
        return _tocc.find(item) != _tocc.end();
    }

private:
    std::map<T, long int> _tocc;
};
```

Here I put all the whole code in a single "file" for simplicity's sake, though I know it is best practice to separate files into headers and source files (which I normally do).

I'd like to know what can be improved about this implementation.

Comment: Since we're implementing a `std::multiset`, perhaps we should use the same public interface?  That would make it easier to switch between this class and the standard one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The rules of five/three/zero

Usually, the existence of a single constructor indicates that the others should get implemented too (or explicitly forbidden/deleted). This is called the [rule of five (or three, depending on the standard)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). However, there is only one member in your class, `_tocc`, and it has well-defined constructors for all the usual cases.

Here, we should follow the rule of *zero*: declare and define no constructors at all, as the default constructors will do the right thing. See also [CppCoreGuidelines C.20](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-zero).

## Use already known data

While there is no bug in your code, there are some optimization flaws. Let's have a look at `tocc<int>::push`, compiled via `gcc 9.2 -S -O3` ([CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/WF_Bk9); I had to `[[gnu::noinline]]` to keep the assembly sane).

```
tocc<int>::push(int const&):
    sub     rsp, 24
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi+16]
    mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rsi]
    test    rdx, rdx
    je      .L31
    lea     r8, [rdi+8]
    mov     rax, rdx
    mov     rsi, r8
    jmp     .L32
.L48:
    mov     rsi, rax
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+16]
    test    rax, rax
    je      .L33
.L32:
    cmp     DWORD PTR [rax+32], ecx
    jge     .L48
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+24]
    test    rax, rax
    jne     .L32
.L33:
    cmp     rsi, r8
    je      .L31
    cmp     DWORD PTR [rsi+32], ecx
    jg      .L31
    mov     rax, r8
    jmp     .L36
.L50:
    mov     rax, rdx
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdx+16]
    test    rdx, rdx
    je      .L49
.L36:
    cmp     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+32]
    jle     .L50
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdx+24]
    test    rdx, rdx
    jne     .L36
.L49:
    cmp     r8, rax
    je      .L41
    cmp     ecx, DWORD PTR [rax+32]
    jl      .L41
    add     QWORD PTR [rax+40], 1
    add     rsp, 24
    ret
.L31:
    mov     rsi, rsp
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp], ecx
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], 1
    call    std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, long> >, bool> std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, long>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, long> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, long> > >::_M_emplace_unique<std::pair<int, long> >(std::pair<int, long>&&)
    add     rsp, 24
    ret
.L41:
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    call    std::__throw_out_of_range(char const*)
```

That's a lot of conditional jumps. 11 jumps depend on `test` or `cmp`. However, we only have a single comparison. What happens here?

Well, first of all, a call to `map<T>::at` isn't free. It always has some additional boundary check, which prevents us from undefined behaviour but exchanges this boon for some additional code and an potential exception.

However, if we're in the second branch in `push`, then we already *know that there is an element*! After all, we *found it beforehand*:

```
void push(const T& item)
{
    if(_tocc.find(item) == _tocc.end())                    
        _tocc.insert(std::pair<T, long int>(item, 1));
    else
        _tocc.at(item)++;  // find() did not return end()!
}
```

Instead of `at`, we should use the iterator for several reasons:

- we already have the element at hand,
- we're guaranteed to have an element, so the boundary check in `at()` is not necessary,
- we don't need to search the element a second time and therefore stay \$\mathcal O(1)\$ instead of \$\mathcal O(\log n)\$

So let's use the iterator instead and let's replace `std::pair<T, long int>` with `std::make_pair` while we're at it:

```
void push(const T& item)
{
    const auto it = _tocc.find(item);
    if(it == _tocc.end()) {          
        _tocc.insert(std::make_pair(item, 1));
    } else {
        it->second++;
    }
}
```

What's the new assembly?

```
tocc<int>::push(int const&):
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+16]
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rsi]
    test    rax, rax
    je      .L31
    lea     rsi, [rdi+8]
    mov     rcx, rsi
    jmp     .L32
.L44:
    mov     rcx, rax
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+16]
    test    rax, rax
    je      .L33
.L32:
    cmp     DWORD PTR [rax+32], edx
    jge     .L44
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+24]
    test    rax, rax
    jne     .L32
.L33:
    cmp     rsi, rcx
    je      .L31
    cmp     DWORD PTR [rcx+32], edx
    jle     .L36
.L31:
    sub     rsp, 24
    lea     rsi, [rsp+8]
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+8], edx
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+12], 1
    call    std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, long> >, bool> std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, long>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, long> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, long> > >::_M_emplace_unique<std::pair<int, int> >(std::pair<int, int>&&)
    add     rsp, 24
    ret
.L36:
    add     QWORD PTR [rcx+40], 1
    ret
```

Only 6 conditional jumps, only ~55% the original amount. However, keep in mind that the reduction of asm instructions was *not* the goal of this section. Instead, we re-used already known values and didn't repeat ourselves (only *one* `find()` call).

The same holds for `pop()`'s usage of `map::erase()`, which can also take an iterator instead of a `Key`, but that's left as an exercise.

## Documentation and (internal) comments

Good job on the comments! However, keep in mind that [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) and other programs use special syntax to discern  documentation comments and implementation comments.

## Naming

The sole member of our class almost has the same name as your class. This makes it somewhat confusing, as we use `_tocc` to actually implement `tocc`. Naming is hard, though, and I cannot come up with a nicer name; `counter`, `key_counter` or `key_counter_map` don't have the same ring to it, although the latter is the most descriptive variant.

## Interface

At the moment, a user must know the name of all items in the `tocc` to check their count afterwards. An iterator interface would be tremendously helpful.

We could even reuse `std::map::const_iterator`, if you only want constant iteration:

```
using iterator_type = std::map<T, long int>::iterator_type;

iterator_type begin() { return _tocc.begin(); }
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `push` class has a big chunk of code and does two lookups in the map.  It can be replaced with one line of code:

```
++_tocc[item];
```

since `operator[]` will add a key/value pair if it does not exist, and default initialize the value (0 in the case of `long int`).

`pop` will do three lookups if the item is found. This can be reduced to one by saving the result of the `_tocc.find` call and using the returned iterator in four places.

`getCount` will do two lookups, and can also save the result of the `find` call and use the iterator.

Neither`getCount` nor `contains` modify the `tocc` object, so they should be declared `const` member functions.